# Un-stick sticky search bar (like on YouTube or Facebook)

Tags: facebook, youtube

Many websites now have a search bar anchored on top of the window, that stays there on scrolling down, like, for example on YouTube or Facebook.

Is there a way to stop this behavior, meaning the search bar should move while scrolling (the "classic" way)?

Comment: There is no way to do this for every website. A script could be made (as mentioned in an answer below) that could change the effect on many websites and that script could be packaged as a browser add-on or something. Right now, there aren't any. (Most commonly, this effect is achieved with a CSS attribute ("position:fixed"). You normally just need to delete that attribute.)

Comment: The question it's too broad because it's not about an specific web application. The apps mentioned are from different companies which could be using different programming styles, frameworks, etc. If you are looking for an web browser extension/add-on recommendation checkout [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change this behaviour out of the box, but there is a way in which you can install some browser plugin and add script (usually JavaScript) to enhance your experience with popular websites (as you mentioned Facebook and YouTube).

Example:
Browser Plugin: Greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
Greasemonkey Wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey
User Script site: http://userscripts.org/

Answer (score 1):

Using Ublock, I am able to get this feature... to an extent. Download UBlock origin for Firefox or Chrome.

After that is done you can right click on any item on a webpage and  block it.

Right click the youtube bar you want to block, click "block element" from the drop down menu. This will then expand a window on the bottom right of the screen. If you click the text it will highlight the item on the page you are about to block. Currently the item on youtube is called "###masthead-positioner". Choosing "create" will block the youtube bar, allowing you to now scroll down and get rid of the large banner they put on every page. This only works on this page, and will disappear after you reload.

I wish I had a better solution, but this works for now.